# How can I make this print with a parser?

Tags: python

So I'm making a coding language which going ok so far, but I've been stuck on this stage for really long, and I just can't figure it out.

Basically in my language, so far you can instruct to print out a string, but all it does is print all of the tokens out of the statement, so if you write in console log:

```
outln "I love SO";
```

It will output:

```
Token('PRINT', 'outln')
Token('QUOTE', '"')
Token('STRING', 'I')
Token('STRING', 'love')
Token('STRING', 'SO')
Token('QUOTE', '"')
Token('ENDLN', ';')
```

Now I'm trying to actually get it to print out the I love SO statement, but here is the problem.

I'm well aware I need AST and a Parser to accomplish this job, but every time I make an attempt at trying to get that to work, it just refuses to do so.

First up I made an AST.py file, and it looks like this:

```
class Print():
  def __init__(self, value):
     self.value = value

  def eval(self):
     print(self.value.eval())
```

And then I created a file named Parser.py that tied these two files together:

```
from rply import ParserGenerator
from ast import Print


class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
         self.pg = ParserGenerator(
           # A list of all token names accepted by the parser.
           ['PRINT', 'QUOTE', 'STRING',
         'ENDLN']
         )

    def parse(self):
         @self.pg.production('program : PRINT QUOTE statement QUOTE ENDLN')
         def program(p):
            return Print(p[2])

         @self.pg.production('statement : STRING')

    def get_parser(self):
         return self.pg.build()
```

Now to tie it all up:

```
from lexer import Lexer
from parser import Parser

lexer = Lexer().get_lexer()
tokens = lexer.lex(input())

for token in tokens:
   print(token)

pg = Parser()
pg.parse()
parser = pg.get_parser()
parser.parse(tokens).eval()
```

Now the lexer isn't the issue, but it's probably necessary for a solution, so here it is:

```
from rply import LexerGenerator

class Lexer():
def __init__(self):
    self.lexer = LexerGenerator()

def _add_tokens(self):
    self.lexer.add('PRINT', r'outln')
    self.lexer.add('QUOTE', r'\"')
    self.lexer.add('STRING', r'\w+')
    self.lexer.add('ENDLN', r';')
    self.lexer.ignore(r'\s+')

def get_lexer(self):
    self._add_tokens()
    return self.lexer.build()
```

And the result is not what I would like to see, a big fat error.

What must I do to not get this result and get the result of "I love SO"? Any help would be apprechiated greatly.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to track down the problem yourself first. Simply telling us that you got an error is not helpful. When posting on Stack Overflow, make sure to ask a **specific** question; "how do I make (dozens of lines of code) work? Please help" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: Does posting the error that I got help? @KarlKnechtel

Comment: That's a start, yes. However, it's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish with the code. It seems as though you intend for your program to not only analyze the source code, but compile and run it. (Or perhaps interpret it?) A compiler is much more than just a lexer and parser.

Comment: Well I'm trying to use rply to make my own print statement, and using the documentation i did well with the lexer part, but i need to actually print out what i wanted it to print using a parser but the documentation is really just showing me how to return equations, but i want to return strings instead.

Comment: Also in addition the error says that there was some kind of unexpected indent, in the parser.py file on line 20.

Comment: This is a broad topic beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question. You need to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) about compiler theory. See for example https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165543/how-to-write-a-very-basic-compiler.

Comment: "Also in addition the error says that there was some kind of unexpected indent, in the parser.py file on line 20." Well, that is just a typo then. You do understand how indentation works generally in Python, yes?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not understanding when i make it so that the error goes away by indenting twice, it says it can't find the get_parser() function

Comment: It is not possible to help you in this format. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is not a discussion forum, nor a chat room.